# When do a second-order-linear homogeneous ODE has a periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was tring to find the sufficient and necessary condition of whether a linear ODE $$a_0\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a_1\frac{dy}{dx}+a_2y=0\quad(*)$$ has a **periodic non-zero** solution over the complex field. Here $a_0\neq 0, a_1, a_2$ are all constant complex numbers. Here's what I've done:

As the characteristic equation of (*), say $a_0\lambda^2+a_1\lambda+a_2=0$ has two roots over $\mathbb{C}$. Denote them as $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, we have $$\lambda_1+\lambda_2=-\frac{a_1}{a_0}, \quad \lambda_1\lambda_2=\frac{a_2}{a_0}$$ Hence we can find the solution $y=c_1\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_1x}+c_2\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_2x}$, $c_1, c_2$ arbitrary constant numbers.

Now suppose the solution has period $T$, so we have $$y(x+T)=c_1\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_1T}\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_1x}+c_2\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_2T}\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_2x}=c_1\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_1x}+c_2\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_2x}=y(x)$$As $\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_1x}, \mathrm{e}^{\lambda_2x}$ **linearly independent**, we must have $$\frac{c_1\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_1T}}{c_2\mathrm{e}^{\lambda_2T}}=\frac{c_1}{c_2},$$ which gives $\lambda_1=\lambda_2.$

**I'm not very sure whether what I've done is correct**, since I used a concept in linear algebra called *linearlly independent*, but I do not know exactly what does it mean in the field of differential equation.

In fact, I couldn't quite catch the key to this type of problems. Here is another similar problem in my assignment sheet, which I also faced some difficulties when trying to solve.

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous $T$-periodic function, prove that $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\beta\frac{dy}{dx}+y=f(t)$$ has only one $T$-periodic solution when $\beta\neq 0$, and find the expression of it.

What is the general method in solving this kind of problem?? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Separate $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ into their real and imaginary parts. You'll see that the solutions are periodic iff $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are purely imaginary (and distinct). As for the second question, it depends on whether you know what Fourier series are.

Comment: Could you please explain more details cuz I'm not that familiar with the situation on $\mathbb{C}$. And, what's the problem with my solution? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The problem with your solution is that $e^{\lambda_1 T} = e^{\lambda_2 T}$ does not imply $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$. It implies $e^{(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) T} = 1$ which is equivalent to $(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) T \in 2 \pi i \mathbb{Z}$. Note also that if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$ then $e^{\lambda_1 x}$ and $e^{\lambda_2 x}$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: Also I misspoke slightly, I didn't see you were allowing the $a_i$ to be complex: you only need one of the $\lambda_i$ to be purely imaginary.